# Accessing items within nested list within list.

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I am trying to return items at a certain position in a list that is nested in another list. I keep on getting TypeError: 'list' object is not callable or 'list' index out of range. I am new to python and am having a lot of trouble with this. Any help is appreciated.

```
`NUM_COLS = int(input("How many columns?"))
NUM_ROWS = int(input("How many rows?"))
row = ["_ " * NUM_COLS]
board = [row* NUM_ROWS]
move= int(input("Which colmn would you like to see?"))
column = []
for row in board:
   column.append(row(move))
return column`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `row` with parenthesis. `row(move)`

Change those to brackets to get the index of a list. `row[move]`

Comment: Thank you! Now I keep getting an error saying the 'column' is undefined after I return column.

Comment: That is likely because column is going out of scope. Scope is a programming concept that limits the visibility of code to other parts of code. You defined a function that returns a value to some other code, but it is not called `column` to that code. Instead, access it through a variable assigned to the function. ex: `a = func()`. `a` is now equal to what `column` returned.